# Include in data table regression coeffiecients, std.errors and Pvalues using R

Tags: r

how do I create a data.table in r with coefficient, std.err and Pvlaues with rqpd regression type? It's easy with the coefficients using `summary(myregression)[2]` but don't know how to get std.err and Pval. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with `broom`:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
#Model
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length~.,data=iris)
#Broom
summaryobj <- tidy(mod)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  term              estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)          2.17     0.280       7.76 1.43e-12
2 Sepal.Width          0.496    0.0861      5.76 4.87e- 8
3 Petal.Length         0.829    0.0685     12.1  1.07e-23
4 Petal.Width         -0.315    0.151      -2.08 3.89e- 2
5 Speciesversicolor   -0.724    0.240      -3.01 3.06e- 3
6 Speciesvirginica    -1.02     0.334      -3.07 2.58e- 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error ```Error: No tidy method for objects of class rqpd.pfe``` since probably it's not working with rqpd

Comment: @Jordan_b Please next time add the data and the methods you used. We don't know which class of functions you are using!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that is working

```
    summ <- summary(myregression, se = "boot")
    summ
    str(summ)
    PValues <- summ$coefficients[,4]
```